# Electron/React cannot access component state changes in ipcRenderer listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, electron, react-functional-component, ipcrenderer

I am using Electron with React and I am facing a little problem.

I am creating a functional component and in the useEffect hook I subscribe to `ipcRenderer` to listen for when ipcMain replies.

When ipcRenderer event triggers I am unable to access the latest state updates. All state variables values inside `ipcRenderer.on` function contain data when the component was initially created.

In the code below `customers` is an array state variable. If I `console.log` its value every time the `ipcRenderer.on` is fired it is always empty. I am absolutely sure this variable is not empty inside the component's context because it contains information that is rendered in a grid. When `ipcRenderer.on` is triggered my grid is reset or cleared. All I am trying to do is refresh a row in the grid when `ipcRenderer.on` is triggered.

```
useEffect(() => {

    // Actions triggered in response to main process replies
    ipcRenderer.on(IPCConstants.UPDATE_SALE_CUSTOMER, (event: any, arg: IUpdateResponse) => {
    
        setIsLoading(false);

        if(!arg.success) {
            notifyError(arg.message);
            return;
        }

        setCustomers(
            customers.map(cst => {
                if(cst.CUS_CustomerId === arg.customer.CUS_CustomerId){
                    cst.RowId = `${generateRandomValue()}`;
                    cst.isActive = arg.customer.isActive;
                }
                return cst;
            })
        )
    });

    return () => {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(IPCConstants.UPDATE_SALE_CUSTOMER);
    };

}, []);
```

Comment: This is because your useEffect has a empty deps array. To fix this add the state variables to the empty array at the end of the useEffect so that they stay up to date inside of the useEffect. no dependencies like how it is now only gives the state of when the component loaded. The useEffect needs to update when the state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {

    // Actions triggered in response to main process replies
    ipcRenderer.on(IPCConstants.UPDATE_SALE_CUSTOMER, (event: any, arg: IUpdateResponse) => {
    
        setIsLoading(false);

        if(!arg.success) {
            notifyError(arg.message);
            return;
        }

        setCustomers(
            customers.map(cst => {
                if(cst.CUS_CustomerId === arg.customer.CUS_CustomerId){
                    cst.RowId = `${generateRandomValue()}`;
                    cst.isActive = arg.customer.isActive;
                }
                return cst;
            })
        )
    });

    return () => {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(IPCConstants.UPDATE_SALE_CUSTOMER);
    };

}, [customers, otherState (if needed)]); // <= whichever state is not up to date
```

- You need to include the proper dependencies.
- the useEffect will keep up to date with these state values
- alternatively if you don't need the functionality of useState (unlikely) you can use useRef and the useEffect will always have the up to date ref without passing it as a dependency.